# "Cannot resolve" warnings with Grails 3 in intellij

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Using Intellij 17.1.3, Grails 3.2.9, Gradle 3.4.1

In Grails application.yml file I see many warnings:

> Cannot resolve configuration property ...

For example: All the properties under "cache:" show the warning. 

`hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`

And these ones have no warnings:
`spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false`

My workmate doesn't see these on his Mac in the same project.

Also I see some similar warnings in build.gradle:

mavenWeb, pom and asNode all show "Cannot resolve symbol"

```
publishing.publications {
mavenWeb(MavenPublication) {
    pom.withXml {
        def pomNode = asNode()
```

Everything "seems" to work OK but I don't like seeing all these warnings. What is causing them?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't support grails specific yml properties yet.